# wcf service - running a very long operation on shared hosting

Tags: wcf, timeout

I've got a winform client, communicating with a remote service. I am running some very long operations (can take a few hours to complete). The service updates the client regarding its advancement.

Currently I am getting bizarre timeouts and "connection forcibly closed" exceptions.
I've read that I could either use windows services or net.tcp protocol to run long operations and update my client.

Though since my service is hosted on some shared hosting,  I have no accessibility to windows services, and since it's out there in the open web I can't use net.tcp (I am no expert, but from what I read I cannot use net.tcp outside of an intranet environment).

So, in short, how do I run a long service operation, that will update my client and avoid all these timeouts?

Thank you